# Why are there two different output voltage ratings on some power supplies? and How it works?

Tags: power-supply, charger, ratings

some power supplies (ex. chargers) have two different output voltage ratings like:

5V 2A  **OR**  9V 2A

[image]

**-why is that?**

**-How the charger knows that my load needs 5V or 9V? and not damaging the load**

**-How the switching work?**

thanks,

Comment: are you sure one of them isn't marked in some way?

Comment: you should include some pictures here

Comment: Also, some adapters have a resistor/element or a switch to change the voltage rating.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power_Delivery_(PD)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge

Huawei might have their own standard. For the details you'll have to ask them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This adapter clearly states "Quick Charge".

To read more about QC, [read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge).

In short: this adapter supports a protocol called "Quick Charge" which
uses communication over the USB datalines to detect if a QC compatible product
is connected.

If a non-QC compatible product is connected, the adapter will output 5 V

If a QC compatible product is connected, the adapter will output 5 V until the product requests 9 V from the adapter. Only then will the adapter output 9V.